# Java Script code not working if URL is not home/root

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-templates

I have a java script code for a top navigation bar. The code only works if I am at the root (home) of the website. For example if you click on the plus icon on the top right corner you are taken to another page and then the menu stops working. I am not good at JS right now and I cannot figure out why. I have guessed this could be due to the fact some of the elements are not loaded when the url is different, but I cannot fix it. I am going to post the CSS and html code to see where SCRIPTS are placed. One fact about the Script that is inside the body of the html file is that I cannot move it to outside body since the menu stops working again. I I think the cause is the same thing, but I cannot fix it.

Please give me an edited code since in another question people gave me ideas, while I tried all of them and none worked. This is just to make sure that any answer is a working answer and it is not just a hunch. Thanks!

Here is a link for the deployed website you can use for your trial and error:

http://ejeddi.pythonanywhere.com/

**js:**

```
var cbpHorizontalMenu =(function() {
    var b = $("#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li"),
        g = b.children("a"),
        c = $("body"),
        d = -1;

    function f() {
        g.on('click', a);
        b.on('click', function(h) {
            h.stopPropagation()
        })

    }

    function a(j) {
        if (d !== -1) {
            b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen")
        }
        var i = $(j.currentTarget).parent("li"),
            h = i.index();
        if (d === h) {
            i.removeClass("cbp-hropen");
            d = -1
        } else {
            i.addClass("cbp-hropen");
            $("cbp-hropen");
            d = h;
            c.off('click').on('click', e)
        }
        return false
    }

    function e(h) {
        b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen");
        d = -1
    }
    return {
        init: f
    }
})();
```

**Base html:**

```
    {% load staticfiles %}

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en" class="no-js">
        <head>
            {% block meta_tags %}{% endblock meta_tags%}

            <title>
                {% block title %}BPM App{% endblock title %} 
            </title>

            {% block stylesheets %}
                <link type="text/javascript" href="{% static 'bpmapp/js/topnavbar.js' %}">
                <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{{STATIC_URL}}/favicon.ico"/>
            {% endblock %}

            {% block javascript %}
                <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <script>
                    $(function() {
                        cbpHorizontalMenu.init();
                    });
                </script>
            {% endblock javascript %}

            {% block extra_head %}{% endblock %}
        </head>

        <body>
            <header class="navbar topnavbar">
                {% include 'bpmapp/_topnavbar.html' %}
            </header>

            <div id="main" role="main">
                <div class="container">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock content %}
                </div>
            </div> {# /#main #}

            <script type='text/javascript' src="static/bpmapp/js/cbpHorizontalMenu.min.js"></script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

**topnavbar html**

```
{% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}


        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bpmapp/css/topnav-default.css' %}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bpmapp/css/topnav-component.css' %}">

            <!-- used for icons in navbar -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        </head>

        <div class="container">
            <header class="clearfix">
                <!--<span>Tagline</span>-->
                <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x" id="icon-home"> </i></a>
                <nav>
                <a href="/process_new/"> <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" id="icon-new-process" data-info="New Process"></i> </a>
                    <!-- 
                    <a href="http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/FullWidthImageSlider/" class="icon-arrow-left" data-info="previous Step">Previous Blueprint</a>
                    <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/?p=14426" class="icon-drop" data-info="Next Step">back to the Codrops article</a>
                     -->
                </nav>
            </header>   

            <div class="nav-main">
                <nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Products</a>
                            <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Learning &amp; Games</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Fallen Angel</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sui Maker</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Wave Master</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Golf Pro</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Utilities</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Education</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Learn Thai</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Math Genius</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Chemokid</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <h4>Professionals</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Success 1.0</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Moneymaker</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Downloads</a>
                            <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Education &amp; Learning</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Learn Thai</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Math Genius</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Chemokid</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <h4>Professionals</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Success 1.0</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Moneymaker</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Entertainment</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Holy Cannoli</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Games</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Fallen Angel</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sui Maker</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Wave Master</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Golf Pro</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Applications</a>
                            <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Learning &amp; Games</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <h4>Utilities</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Education</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Learn Thai</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Math Genius</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Chemokid</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <h4>Professionals</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Success 1.0</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Moneymaker</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Projects</a>
                            <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Learning &amp; Games</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Fallen Angel</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sui Maker</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Wave Master</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Golf Pro</a></li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Entertainment</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Holy Cannoli</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

        </div>
```

**topnavbar default CSS:**

```
/* General Demo Style */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);

@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontawesome';
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome.svg#fontawesome') format('svg'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body, html { font-size: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

/* Reset */
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}


body {
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #47a3da;
}

a {
    color: #f0f0f0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: yellow;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.container{
    padding-top:0px;
}


.container > header {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 70em;
    margin: 0 auto; /* remove auto to push the h1 text to left*/
    padding: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
}

/* Brand Name Text */
.container > header h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top:0;
}

.container > header span {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.5em;
    padding: 0 0 0.1em 0.1em;
}

.container > header nav {
    float: right;
    text-align:bottom;
    padding-top:0.1em;
}

/* next previous icons*/
/*
.container > header nav a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: transparent;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
    border: 4px solid #47a3da;
    text-indent: -8000px;
}
*/

/* after click next previous icons*/
.container > header nav a:after {
    content: attr(data-info);
    color: #47a3da;
    position: absolute;
    width: 600%;
    top: 120%;
    text-align: right;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.container > header nav a:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
/* hover next previous icons*/
/*
.container > header nav a:hover {
    background: #47a3da;
}
*/

.icon-drop:before, 
.icon-arrow-left:before {
    font-family: 'fontawesome';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 2;
    text-align: center;
    color: #47a3da;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-indent: 8000px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.container > header nav a:hover:before {
    color: #fff;
}

.icon-drop:before {
    content: "\e000";
}

.icon-arrow-left:before {
    content: "\f060";
}

.fa{
    color:#999;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.fa:hover{
    color: #47a3da;
    /*color:rgb(20,220,180); ----- green ----- */
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

**topnavbar component CSS:**

```
/* menu separator */
.cbp-hrmenu {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0em;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #47a3da;
}

/* general ul (div of tabs) */
.cbp-hrmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* first level ul style (div of tabs)*/
.cbp-hrmenu > ul,
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 70em;
    margin: 0 auto; /*remove auto to push tabs to left*/
    padding: 0 1.875em;

}
/* tabs individually + the menu that drops*/
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* link (text) of tabs */
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a {
    font-size:1.1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0.1em 1em; /* height of tabs*/
    color: #999;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius:0.5em 0.5em 0em 0em;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
}
/* hover tabs' text */
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
    /*color: #47a3da;
    transition: color 0.2s linear;*/
    color:#47a3da;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

/* links inside the drop down menu */
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li.cbp-hropen > a,
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li.cbp-hropen > a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: #47a3da;
}

/* sub-menu (the one that drops and contains options)*/
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #47a3da;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.cbp-hropen .cbp-hrsub {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner > div {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 2em 0;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:before,
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner > div a {
    line-height: 2em;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner > div a:hover {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:yellow;
}


.cbp-hrsub h4 {
    color: #afdefa;
    padding: 2em 0 0.6em;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 160%;
    font-weight: 300;
}

/* Examples for media queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 52.75em) { 

    .cbp-hrmenu {
        font-size: 80%;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 43em) { 

    .cbp-hrmenu {
        font-size: 120%;
        border: none;
    }

    .cbp-hrmenu > ul,
    .cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner {
        padding: 0 2em;
        font-size: 75%;
    }

    .cbp-hrmenu > ul > li {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #47a3da;
    }

    .cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a { 
        display: block;
        padding: 1em 3em;
    }

    .cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub { 
        position: relative;
    }

    .cbp-hrsub h4 {
        padding-top: 0.6em;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 36em) { 
    .cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner > div {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        padding: 0 2em;
    }
}
```

Comment: `I am good at JS right now` - use your browsers **developer** tools console to see the error ... check what `http://ejeddi.pythonanywhere.com/process_new/static/bpmapp/js/cbpHorizontalMenu.min.js` returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the main problem in your code that I can see:

you are using static files, so they are located in the url: http://yourdomain.com/static, but you are trying to load http://yourdomain.com/process_new/static/

you can fix it by 2 ways:

The first way is changing the src attribute in the script tag and adding a "/" at the beginning. It will get the js file from the root:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="/static/bpmapp/js/cbpHorizontalMenu.min.js"></script>
```

Another way to fix it is using the Django static template tag. It will create the url of the static file for you:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'bpmapp/js/cbpHorizontalMenu.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Don't forget to add this tag at the beginning of the template file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Comment: How did you debug that? did you use browser inspection? I tried to use it for debugging but I could not find a way to see where the error was

Comment: also I already asked this question, but the answers did not work. I want to move `<script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'bpmapp/js/cbpHorizontalMenu.min.js' %}"></script> ` to block Javascript, but when I move that, the menu does not work. Do you know why?

Comment: it depends the version of Django: if you are using <1.10, then the staticfiles loads a template tag that can manage non-local storage where static can't.  if you are using >=1.10, then load static uses the same load staticfiles, so you must use just one of them.

Comment: With respect to the debug, I use Chrome and I could see the problem in the tab "Network"